# Calculate percentage of a grouping column in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

Calculate percentage of  "TotalFound, NotFound" 
I need to calculate the percentage of the subgroup "compare".

[image]

Comment: Please add more detail to what you are trying to achieve, it is currently very unclear what you are asking.

Comment: I have a matrix table, In which I have two sub groups in each axis X (Row)and Y (Column). Example: X1,X2 and Y1,Y2. Now im trying to calculate the percentage of Y2 against X1 and X2. Im getting a wrong percentgage with this expression => =iif(Sum(Fields!Total_Count.Value,"Y2")=0,0, Sum(Fields!FoundInCMDB.Value,"X1") / Sum(Fields!Total_Count.Value,"Y2")). I really wish I could attach a screen shot - but since im new the site is not allowing.

Answer (score 1):

If you name the textboxes containing your totals, you should be able to use reportitems:

```
= ReportItems!FoundInCMDB_Total.Value / ReportItems!NotFoundInCMDB_Total.Value
```

Just select each textbox containing the totals relevant to the percentage and change the name in properties. Then in the textbox you want your percentage to appear in type =ReportItems! and a list should appear including the named textboxes.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer for the (unclear) question I've tried ask above. SSRS calculates percentage group only when you total column is inside the same group. This way you can call the total as an expression in your percentage column to do calculate %. But if the Percentage is outside your X/Y group you need to mention the group name like =((Fields!Total.Value,"X")*100/sum(Fields!Total.Value,"X"))&"%"

Thanks,
Kavin